# pdfMake in deno from a CDN

Tags: cdn, deno, pdfmake

I want to use pdfMake in deno and not host the pdfMake files and vfs_fonts on my server, by using a CDN line CDNJS or esm.sh.

I have the following code in the to of my app.js file:

```
import pdfMake from "https://esm.sh/pdfmake"
import * as pdfFonts from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.4/vfs_fonts.min.js"
```

but I get the following errors:

```
[!] [#0] starting `deno run -A app.js`
Download https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.4/vfs_fonts.js
Download https://deno.land/x/md5/mod.ts
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pdfMake')
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
                    ^
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.4/vfs_fonts.js:1:21
[E] [daem] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting ...
```

I am not sure how to import or load the vfs_fonts from the CDN.  Please note that my aim is to use a CDN for getting pdfMake and it's fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the app.js file so that I only load the pdfmake from the CDN. I then load the fonts seperatly from the CDN into the pdfMake object:

```
import pdfMake from "https://esm.sh/pdfmake"

pdfMake.fonts = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
    bold: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
    italics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
  },
  Merriweather: {
    normal: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Regular.ttf',
    bold: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Medium.ttf',
    italics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-MediumItalic.ttf'
  },
}
```

Comment: I have been looking for this going on 3 years now. The creator of `pdfmake` insists in using webpack Node.... What a waste.